# how can access to schema remote powershell?

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

I have a C# code for accessing remote PowerShell and got this error after running: access in denied. 
 the code is  :

```
string shell = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";
var target = new Uri("http://Computername/wsman");

Pipeline p = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
SecureString passing = new SecureString();
string password = "pass";
foreach (char c in password)
{
    passing.AppendChar(c);
}
passing.MakeReadOnly();
var cred = new PSCredential(@"Domain\User", passing);
var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(target, shell, cred); runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);    
 runSpace.Open();
```

this error is occurred because I can not access to this address: http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell

after enter this address for connecting to it , show this message: An error occurred while processing your request.

Is there another address for schema or another way to write this code?

please help me.
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First, try to access the remote machine from PowerShell first.  It will be easier to debug the connection problem there IMO (instead of C#).  Can you connect with the following command (from a 64-bit console):

```
$config = 'Microsoft.PowerShell'
$connuri = 'http://Computername:5985/wsman'
$s = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri $connuri -ConfigurationName $config -Credential (Get-Credential)
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {Get-PSSessionConfiguration} | Format-List *
```

If that works then perhaps you're just missing the port number or there's a coding issue in your C#.  However that would at least rule out a PowerShell configuration issue (which I suspect).

Comment: thanks, no , this command give this error in last line: access in denied.   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], InvalidOperationException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand.  but I can connect to remote powershell with EnterPSSession.

Comment: and I have another problem: when the internet is connected, the remote connection to powershell with enterPSSesion doesn't work and get this error:  Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot complete the operation within the time specified. Check if the machine name is valid and is reachable over the network and firewall exception for Windows Remote Management service is enabled.  please help me. thanks alot.

Comment: Is the network location set to Public on this machine? FYI http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/04/03/setting-network-location-to-private.aspx

Comment: I did instruction of MSDN but the powershell give same error: access is denied. for asp.net code, should I configure the web.config?